# Rails, activerecord query with calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, report

I have been struggling a big problem with this and I have finally decided to seek some help from the community.

I am trying to generate a report that uses the following models.

```
class Volunteer < User
  has_one :volunteer_profile
  has_many :junior_leagues
  has_many :refresher_courses
  has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteer_programs, foreign_key: "user_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_profile
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  has_one :volunteer_profile
  before_validation :generate_password

  has_many :junior_leagues, foreign_key: "volunteer_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :refresher_courses, foreign_key: "volunteer_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users_mentors, class_name: 'UsersMentor', foreign_key: 'mentor_id'
  has_many :mentees, through: :users_mentors, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :volunteer_schedules, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :programs, through: :volunteer_schedules

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_mentors
```

This is a volunteer class and this is a Volunteer Schedule:

```
  class VolunteerSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :program_type_name

  ROLE = { lead_volunteer: 1, shadowing: 2 }

  validates :end_time, :start_time, :volunteer_id, presence: true
  validates :volunteer_id, uniqueness: {scope: [:start_time, :end_time, :program_type_id],     message: "Already added."}

  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :program_type
  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :volunteer_program
  # VolunteerProgram

  before_validation :set_program_type

  ##SCOPES##
  scope :where_date, -> (date) { where('DATE(start_time) = ?', date) }
  scope :personal_shoppers, -> { where(program_type_id: ProgramType.find_by(name:    ProgramType::PERSONAL_SHOPPERS).try(:id)) }
```

I am trying to run a query that will allow me to get a list of Volunteers and the total hours worked for each volunteer based on a date range.

Here is the controller method I have so far:

```
def volunteer_hours
@volunteer_names = Array.new

@volunteer_schedule_times = VolunteerSchedule.joins(:volunteer).where( start_time: params[:vol_start_time]..params[:vol_end_time] )

@volunteer_schedule_times.each do |current_schedule_times|
   @volunteer_names << current_schedule_times.volunteer.name
 end

@volunteer_names.uniq!

hours_for_each_volunteer = @volunteer_names.each do |volunteer|
  VolunteerSchedule.joins(:volunteer).where(start_time: params[:vol_start_time], name: volunteer)
 end
```

I have to group, `group_by`, I wrote a bunch of helper methods, but quickly got mixed up and had a bunch of scoping issues. I need help with this one and

Oh a quick look at the schema if case it's helpful:

```
  create_table "volunteer_schedules", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "start_time"
t.datetime "end_time"
t.integer  "program_id"
t.integer  "volunteer_id"
t.integer  "role"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "program_type_id"
t.integer  "volunteer_program_id"
end
```

And Volunteers Inherit from users:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email"
t.string   "encrypted_password",                 default: "",   null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",                      default: 0,    null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "avatar"
t.string   "phone"
t.boolean  "phone_is_cell",                      default: true
t.string   "second_alternate_phone"
t.boolean  "second_alternate_phone_is_cell",     default: true
t.string   "type"
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "middle_initial"
t.string   "last_name"
t.date     "date_of_birth"
t.boolean  "veteran"
t.string   "street_address"
t.string   "apartment_unit"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "zip"
t.boolean  "receive_appointment_text_reminders", default: true
t.boolean  "alternate_phone"
t.boolean  "alternate_phone_is_cell",            default: true
t.boolean  "active",                             default: true
t.boolean  "star_client"
t.float    "gpa"
end
```

I could use some serious help with this one.